# Code to match data held in an sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

What im trying to do is create an ATM , so when the user selects their account number from the combo box that holds all the account numbers from an sql database, and then enters the correct pin it allows the user to access form2. Any suggestions on how to do this.I think i need an if statement so when enter is pressed if the pin is correct continue to the next page but if is not correct ill have a message box displaying you have 2 attempts left, i just don't no the code needed to interact with the database to match the Account number with the correct pin. The code i have already is as follows:

```
    private void BtnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (true)
        {
            Form2 frm2;                        
            frm2 = new Form2();           
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have two attempts remaining");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11.ATMCards);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your should use this query if you are using ComboBox and an textbox

```
  string Sqlcommand="Select PinNumber from [Your Table Name]
   where
   AccountNumber='"+Combobox.SelectedItem+"' ;


  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
      string Sqlcommand="Select PinNumber from [Your Table Name]
      where
       AccountNumber='"+Combobox.SelectedItem+"' ;            
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sqlcommand, con);
        con.Open();
        Object pinnumber = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();            
        if (pinnumber != null)
        {
            LblError.Visible = false;
            LblError.Text = "";
            if (pinnumber .ToString() == TextBox1.Text)
            {
                Response.Redirect("");
            }
            else if (TypeUser.ToString() == "HR")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have two attempts remaining");
            }
         }
```

Hope this works for u..if u have any doubts ask me ...

Comment: Ive used the wizard to set up the connection and a dataset so would i need all of this code ? or is this to create the connection? is there a way of me using an integer to hold the currently selected account number and to then use my dataset to locate the row that holds that account number and pin number i.e something like datasetATM1.Tables("ACCOUNTS").Rows(Index).item("PIN") ? (Index is a variable holding the currently selected account number in the combobox). Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework to me but you need a connection object with a connection string and a sql adapter constructor with your SQL in it before you can call the Fill command to populate your Dataset.

You then need to take the pin number they have entered and either find it in your dataset or execute an SQL statement at that point rather than in your Form_Load event.  You will need an numberOfAttempts variable that needs incrementing on each failure and resetting to 0 if the pin is correct. Your if statement then needs to check this variable.

Your SQL will need to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTTABLE 
WHERE 
ACCOUNT = SELECTEDACCOUNTNUMBER 
AND 
PINNUMBER = ENTEREDPINNUMBER
```